# Sketchup HTML:DialogFill fill Tags from selected csv file

Tags: javascript, ruby, sketchup

Using Sketchup HTML:Dialog I am trying to fill in some input tags from a csv file.

I don't get an error, the code does not seem to get past `reader.onload = function(event)`

Has anybody had the same issue and found a solution?

[image]

```
dialog = UI::HtmlDialog.new(
    {
      :dialog_title => "csv",
      :scrollable => true,
      :resizable => true,
      :width => 500,
      :height => 600,
      :left => 200,
      :top => 200,
      :min_width => 150,
      :min_height => 150,
      :max_width =>100,
      :max_height => 50,
      :style => UI::HtmlDialog::STYLE_DIALOG
    })
    html = "
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Dave Loves You</title>
    <style>
        label {
            display: block;
            font: 1rem 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
    }

    input,
    label {
            margin: 0.4rem 0;
    }

</style>
    </head>
    <h1>Insert Box Info</h1>
    <script>
    function mssgme(){
        document.getElementById('f_name').value = 'I have changed!';
    }
    function sendDataToSketchUp() {
        var nm = document.getElementById('nam');
        var user_input1 = document.getElementById('id1');
        var user_input2 = document.getElementById('id2');
        var user_input3 = document.getElementById('id3');
        sketchup.getUserInput(nm.value, user_input1.value, user_input2.value, user_input3.value)
    }
    </script>
    <script>

    function get_Info(){
        var csvFile = document.getElementById('f_csv');     

        console.log(csvFile.value);         
        document.getElementById('f_name').value = csvFile.value;
        var fileList  = csvFile.files[0];
        console.log('line 58');             
        var reader  = new FileReader();
        console.log('line 60');         
        reader.onload = function(event) {
            var content = event.target.result;
            console.log('line 63');         
            var rows = content.split('/n');
            var ids = rows[0].split(',');  // Split first row to get IDs
            var values = rows[1].split(','); // Split second row to get values

            for (let i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
                var element = document.getElementById(ids[i].trim());
                if (element) {
                    element.value = values[i].trim();
                    alert(values[i]);
                }
            }
            alert('success');
            };
            
        }
        
        </script>
        
    <body>
    <h1>Open CSV and fill input boxes</h1>   

        
        <label for='f_name'>First Name:</label>
        <input type='text' id='f_name' name='f_name' value='' />
        <label for='l_name'>Last Name:</label>
        <input type='text' id='l_name' name='l_name' value='' />
        <label for='age'>Age:</label>
        <input type='number' id='age' name='age' value='' />
        <button onclick='get_Info()'> we </button>
        <input type='file' id='f_csv' onchange='get_Info()' accept='.csv'>

    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
    "
    dialog.set_html(html)
    dialog.show
```